# Creating an Acumatica Screen that uses an unbound DAC

Tags: acumatica

I have a process where I need to create a screen that would be used to send data off to a third-party provider and return the response. Simple enough.
I would prefer not to create a table or stored procedure in the database as the basis for this DAC, so my thought is to create a  DAC for the screen that has no bound fields.
I have created the DAC and the BLC for this, but am having difficulty getting this to work since the table does not actually exist in the database and Acumatica likes to have the actual table or stored procedure exist.
I could probably accomplish my task by creating stored procedure, but prefer not to.

Any tips, thoughts on a best approach for a situation like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need PXFilter. PXFilter data view always creates a single data record and never retrieves or saves this dat arecord to the database. It works only with UI adn doesn't invoke any request to db. If you need to have a grid, and provide some data for it, consider PXProcessing, PXProcessingJoin, PXFilteredProcessing, PXFilteredProcessingJoin instead of PXSelect. Also you can override completely some of your views, without having need to take data from db.

consider following example:

```
public PXFilteredProcessing<WorklogInfo, JiraFilterItem> JiraWorklog;
//some of other declarations
protected IEnumerable jiraWorklog()
{
      //return list of records to grid      
}
```

Comment: Yes, changing to the PXFilter view type allowed me to get past my roadblock. thank you.